# Reference counter does not include chapter number

Tags: cross-referencing, environments, counters

Trying to get reference numbers right to a custom defined environment. In short I have:

```
\newcounter{MathToolBox}[chapter]\setcounter{MathToolBox}{0}
\newcommand{\theBox}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{MathToolBox}}

\newenvironment{MathToolBox}[2][]{%
    \refstepcounter{MathToolBox}
 ......
      }
}
```

And further inside the document:

```
\begin{MathToolBox}[Title]
....Text.....

 \label{mtb:label}
\end{MathToolBox}
```

Now, when I try to reference to this MathToolBox with `/ref{mtb:label}` I get the correct number of the toolbox but unfortunately, I do not get something in style of "chapter.numberOfToolbox".

Anyway, what would be the standard way to handle this? Inside default predefined equation environment it just works fine but I don't see how I would be able to append the chapter number to it with a dot in between because (of course) `\refstepcounter` just takes one (counter-type) argument. I expect this to be trivial but nonetheless I couldn't find anything on this online. 
Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try `\counterwithin{MathToolBox}{chapter}` in the place of `\newcommand{\theBox}`.

Comment: I think the answer to your question can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903254/how-to-define-in-latex-a-new-counter-that-includes-the-chapter-number-too